# Bootstrap Vue change active button color

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap with Vue.js.

I have a form-checkbox-group like this

```js
      <b-form-group label="Select flow" v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }">
        <b-form-checkbox-group
          v-model="selected"
          :options="options"
          :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
          buttons
          button-variant="primary"
          size="lg"
          name="buttons-2"
        ></b-form-checkbox-group>
      </b-form-group>
```

I would like the selected button to be set to a specific color (rathen than it being just a little bit darker).

I tried adding the code below but unfortunately it doesn't work

```css
.active {
  background: rgb(243, 16, 0) !important;
}
```

Full code here:

```js
<template>
  <div class="Overview">
          <b-form-group label="Select flow" v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }">
        <b-form-checkbox-group
          v-model="selected"
          :options="options"
          :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
          buttons
          button-variant="primary"
          size="lg"
          name="buttons-2"
        ></b-form-checkbox-group>
      </b-form-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Control",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "F1_Water",
      options: [
        { value: "F1_Water", text: "Water" },
        { value: "F1_Clean", text: "Cleaning solution" },
        { value: "F1_None", text: "None" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.active {
  background: rgb(243, 16, 0) !important;
}
</style>
```

[image: Button group]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed the `<style>` opening tag after the `</script>` closing tag.

Have in mind that you shouldn't include `scoped` to it because the target of the css style is a different component (the `b-form-checkbox-group` component), so it would be just

```css
<style>
  .active {
    background: rgb(243, 16, 0) !important;
  }
</style>
```

Here are the docs for the [scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) feature in Vue.js.

Comment: Ohh, I had no idea that the word `scoped` was so meaningfull. Indeed, removing it makes the css working perfectly as expected ! The missing `style` opening was just a mistake when removing unecessary code for this question, I'll edit this. Thanks !

Comment: You should only remove `scoped` if you want this CSS to apply to your entire project.
However, if you only want this CSS to apply to the component its in, you need to keep `scoped`. If you keep scoped you need to use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) to target the sub-component.

Comment: In general, you should always use `scoped`, to avoid CSS bleeding into other components, since it's very unpredictable. If you want global styles, you should create a global style sheet where you keep global styling.